# How much did the bananas cost

Tags: lateral-thinking

I went to the grocers today. I  brought three bananas from the grocers and paid for them. How much did I pay for the three bananas.

Comment: Please modify this question so that it is possible to recognise the intended correct solution from the several unintended plausible ones. This looks like a decent puzzle otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

> Too much, since you brought them.

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing

As

> Your description says you "brought" not bought!

Comment: i hope this isn't the answer... lol

Comment: Do you still say you 'pay' for something if it is for free?

Comment: Pay thru your nose if you are arrested!